# Why am I getting an error about NSCollectionView not being nil?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, nscollectionview

This is my `BookListObject.h`:

```
@ property (nonatomic,retain)NSImage *bookImage;

@ property (nonatomic,copy)  NSString *bookName;

and I connect these bindings:

bookImage ----- representedObject.bookImage

bookName ------representedObject.bookName

arrayController-------arrangedObject

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    BookListObject * book=[[BookListObject alloc] init];

    book.bookName=@"unknown";

    book.bookImage=[NSImage imageNamed:@"dis"];

    _bookList=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:book, nil];

    [arrayController addObject:_bookList];
}
```

I have seen [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dw-sHMTsMVs).

When I run my project, it crashes and prompts that `NSCollectionView` item prototype must not be nil.

I found the following method, but it doesn't work:

```
NSCollectionViewItem *itemPrototype = [self.storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"collectionViewItem"];
self.bookListCV.itemPrototype=itemPrototype;
```

The problem remains. What should I do? How  can I bind the `collectionView` with `collectionViewItem` in the storyboard? I think XCode6 supports it only when you use xib.